# How to extract values from defaultdict with nested list values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I have a `defaultdict` with nested list values and I need to extract the values as shown in the output.

```
dd = defaultdict(list)
print(dd)
```

Input:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
'1': [[['Peter', '100'], ['John', '200'], ['Carlos', '150'], ['Rick', '25']], ['HR']], 
'2': [[['Albert', '200']], ['Travel']], 
'3': [[['Mick', '300']], ['IT']]
})
```

output:

```
1,Peter,100,HR
1,John,200,HR
1,Carlos,150,HR
1,Rick,25,HR
2,Albert,200,Travel
3,Mick,300,IT
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate on your list value to get desired output as:

```
for k, v in dd.items():
    for vv in v[0]:
       print(','.join([k, vv[0], vv[1], v[1][0]]))
```

Here `v[0]` is your list of names and number i.e. `[['Peter', '100']...]`,
and `v[1]` is the list of department i.e. `['HR']`.

Above code will print:

```
1,Peter,100,HR
1,John,200,HR
1,Carlos,150,HR
1,Rick,25,HR
2,Albert,200,Travel
3,Mick,300,IT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple nested loop:

```
for k,v in dd.items():
    for e in v[0]:
        print(','.join((k,*e,v[1][0])))
```

Output:

```
1,Peter,100,HR
1,John,200,HR
1,Carlos,150,HR
1,Rick,25,HR
2,Albert,200,Travel
3,Mick,300,IT
```